# What is the type of nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, nullptr

The Standard states, that `nullptr` is a pointer literal of type `std::nullptr_t` (2.14.7). And 18.2p9 defines `nullptr_t` by

```
namespace std {
  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
}
```

By 7.1.6.2p4 `decltype(nullptr)` is the type of the expression `nullptr`, which is by definition `std::nullptr_t` (since the expression `nullptr` is a prvalue). Substituting that into the definition of `nullptr_t` results in

```
typedef nullptr_t nullptr_t
```

On the other hand a typedef specifier does not introduce a new type, it's just a name for another existing type. So, what is exactly `nullptr_t`? I'm not able to comprehend these definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally there is an entity that is the *null pointer constant type*.  It is one of the fundamental types.

The keyword, literal and expression `nullptr` has this type.  `decltype(nullptr)` refers to this type.

However the *name* `std::nullptr_t` is not a keyword (not even a context-sensitive one), and so the name does not exist until declared.  If you refer to the name `std::nullptr_t` without declaring it, it is an error, as for any undeclared name.

So although the *type* exists at the start of translation like any fundamental type, the *name* does not exist.

In fact there are other fundamental types that do not have a "single spelling", such as short int.  A short int can be refered to as `short`, `short int`, `signed short int`, `signed short`, or any permutation thereof.

It is also not dissimilar to the relationship between the `typeid` operator (keyword), and the type of the `typeid(...)` expression, `std::typeinfo`.  `typeinfo` is also not a keyword and the name does not exist before being declared.

Basically, you are conflating an *entity* (the null pointer constant type) with a *name* (`std::nullptr_t`)

If you ask why didn't the language designers specify `nullptr_t` and `typeinfo` as keywords, I would speculate that they are not common enough to risk a name collision with a user-defined name with the same spelling.  Recall that such a collision would occur in any and all scopes.

Comment: Where is _null pointer constant type_ defined in the standard?

Comment: @MWid: It isn't explictly, I'm using the term for exposition to refer to the type of `nullptr`, as distinct from a C++ _name_ for that type.  I agree that the standard could be clearer about the distinction, most of what I describe is an implicit consequence - but entities and names are distinguished in the preamble of clause 3.

Answer (score 10):

It is implementation-specific. What is important is that (p. 18.2/9 of the C++11 Standard):

> [...] The type for which `nullptr_t` is a synonym has the characteristics described in 3.9.1 and 4.10. [...]

As long as it behaves like the Standard specifies in those two paragraphs, it can be anything.

I believe the logical fallacy in your argument is that this:

> By 7.1.6.2p4 `decltype(nullptr)` is the type of the expression `nullptr`, which is by definition `std::nullptr_t` (since the expression `nullptr` is a prvalue)

Does **not** mean that `nullptr_t` is *not* a type alias. For instance, if I define:

```
typedef decltype(42) foo;
```

I can say that the type of the expression:

```
42
```

Is `foo`. Yet, `foo` is just an alias for another type (`int`).

Comment: The standard explicitely states, that the type of `nullptr` is `std::nullptr_t`. So 18.2p9 comes down to `nullptr_t` is a synonym for itself.

Comment: @MWid: No, it is a synonym for something that is not specified by the standard. The fact that the type of `nullptr` is `std::nullptr_t` does not mean that `std::nullptr_t` cannot be an alias for some other type. That's what I tried to communicate in my answer (especially in the last example), although I have the feeling I haven't formulated it well

Comment: 7.1.3p1 states that typedef declares identifiers that can be used later for naming fundamental or compound types. Is `std::nullptr_t` a fundamental type?

Comment: @MWid: That's not what you should focus on. The point is that when you say "the type of `expr` is `X`", this does not mean that `X` cannot be a synonym for another type. So when the standard says "the type of `nullptr` is `nullptr_t`", this does not mean that `nullptr_t` cannot be a synonym for another type

Comment: Well, your answer convinced me that `nullptr_t` is a synonym for another type. And you say, that this type is not specified by the standard. In conclusion this means, that `nullptr_t` is a synonym for an unspecified fundamental type?

Comment: @MWid: Yes, `std::nullptr_t` is a fundamental type.  It is also a scalar type and object type.

Comment: Wouldn`t it be a better solution to add `nullptr_t` as simple-type-specifier to the core language?

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge is not sufficient to answer this last question, but I believe there are good reasons why the Committee decided to define it this way. Perhaps @HowardHinnant can provide an insight :)

Comment: @HowardHinnant I thought, I got it, but no. `nullptr_t` is a fundamental type and at the same time, it is an alias for another fundamental type otherwise the `typedef` definition would be ill-formed. So the core language contains an anspecified (and not mentioned) fundamental type.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with this area either.  However N2431 may hold the answer to this question: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thank you for the link, I think it does shed some light

Comment: @MWid: Perhaps one of the reasons is that introducing a new keyword would have been a problem for old programs that used the name `nullptr_t` (perhaps there aren't any, but hard to tell). Making `nullptr_t` a keyword would likely make those programs ill-formed. This way, you can use the `nullptr_t` name for your own purposes, and if you need to refer to the type of `nullptr` through a name, then you can use `std::nullptr_t`

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that `std::nullptr_t` is a typedef (in `<cstddef>`) for the otherwise unnamed fundamental type of which `nullptr` is an instance.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that it is correct to say, that the type of the expression `42` is `foo`. The type of this expression is `int`, for which `foo` is another name. But `foo` itself is not a type.

Comment: @MWid: I see what you mean, but I'm not sure whether you should take it to that level of precision. IOW, since `foo` is a name for `int`, you *can* say that the type of `42` is `foo`. While it may be more precise saying that the type of `42` is `int`, it is not *wrong* to say that the type of `42` is `foo` - because you have defined `foo` as an alias for `int`, so they mean the same thing.

Comment: In few words: types are not their names.

Comment: I cannot find any of the references to the C++ standard that you have posted: 3.9.1 , 4.10 , 7.1.6.2p4 . Would you mind showing me where I can find these sections ? :/