# Does `sizeof` *really* evaluate to a `std::size_t`? Can it?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, language-lawyer

Take the following standard passage:

> `[C++11: 5.3.3/6]:` The result of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` is a constant of type `std::size_t`. *[ Note:* `std::size_t` is defined in the standard header `<cstddef>` (18.2). *—end note ]*

Now:

> `[C++11: 18.2/6]:` The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

Granted, the passage doesn't require that `size_t` is a type alias defined with `typedef`, but since it's explicitly stated to be made available by the standard header `<cstddef>`, I think we can take as read that failing to include `<cstddef>` should remove any guarantee that `size_t` shall be available to a program.

However, according to that first quote, we can regardless obtain an expression of type `std::size_t`.

[We can actually demonstrate both of these facts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2773cc8d2a92d4e7):

```
int main()
{
    typedef decltype(sizeof(0)) my_size_t;

    my_size_t x   = 0;  // OK
    std::size_t y = 1;  // error: 'size_t' is not a member of 'std'
}
```

`std::size_t` is not visible to the program, but `sizeof(0)` still gives us one? Really?

**Is it therefore not correct to say that `5.3.3/6` is *flawed*, and that it actually has "the same type as whatever `std::size_t` resolves to", but *not* `std::size_t` itself?**

Sure, the two are one and the same if `std::size_t` is a type alias but, again, nowhere is this actually required.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "the same type as whatever std::size_t resolves to" is `std::size_t`, regardless of how `size_t` is defined or whether it's an alias for anything. That said, I'm not enough of a C++ language lawyer to answer this question.

Comment: "I think we can take as read that failing to include <cstddef> should remove any guarantee that size_t shall be available to a program" - you need to include `cstddef` to use the `size_t` name, but not the `size_t` type.

Comment: @user2357112: `int` and `long` are distinct types, despite having the same properties on my platform.

Comment: @user2357112: That might be the answer. I'd like to see a further exploration of that idea!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Related: `operator new`, `operator delete` and variations thereof are also available without the inclusion of any header files, but somewhere in the standard (I suppose 3.7.4 but not sure), I read that using them "does not make the operator `std::operator new(std::size_t)` visible", or something like that.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't expect `y` to compile just because `x` did.

Comment: @H2CO3 the type is available in the language, no library needed. The library provides a  convenient name for it, that's all.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It's just that the standard wording refers to this type with _this_ name, which seems to be trying to make a binding between `sizeof` and _this_ name, which is wrong?! Of course I'm being massively picky...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Do not confuse the map for the territory.

Types can be named by typenames.  These typenames can be built-in, they can be user-defined types, or they could even be `template` parameters and refer to multiple different types depending on the instantiation.

But the names are not the types.  Clearly standard does not mandate that all types have names -- the classic `struct {}` is a type without a name.

`std::size_t` is a typename.  It names the type that `sizeof(expression)` returns.

The compiler could have a canonical name for the type -- `__size_t` would be one way for it to have a unique built-in canonical typename.

The standard guarantees in that clause that whatever the type of `sizeof(expression)` is, once you `#include <cstddef>`, the name `std::size_t` now refers to that type.

In the standard, they refer to types by names.  They do not say "the type that this typename refers to", but simply say "the type $NAME$".  The compiler could decide that `int` is another name for `__int_32_fast` if it wanted to, and the standard would have no objection either.

This same thing happens with `std::nullptr_t` and `std::initializer_list<Ts>` and `std::type_info`: use of variables of those types does not always require that the header that provides you with a name for those types be included in your program.

The traditional C/C++ built-in types all had canonical names that did not require a header.  The downside is that this breaks existing code, as new typenames in the global scope collide with other identifiers.

By having "nameless types", where you can get a name for them via including a header file, we avoid that problem.

Comment: What do you think about 5.7.6? Where it does exactly what I suggest, for `std::ptrdiff_t`. Isn't this, at the very least, an inconsistency in the choice of wording?

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit Yes, inconsistency in wording.  Same with `nullptr_t` -- lots of inconsistent wording.  Probably could be cleared up?  But is pretty esoteric, is it worth the effort?

Comment: Nope, doubt it. Just wanted us all to agree :)

Comment: If we add this in, that's the answer I think

Comment: Types and typenames... this reminds me variables' names and pointers. We can access a variable by name, but also can access it by pointer which can be returned from a function (in this case we don't need to include a header that declares variable's name). Data is just a record in memory which can be accessed by name or by pointer. Similarly types are records in compiler memory which can be referred from program by typename or by what operators return (using auto or decltype).

Answer (score 52):

The standard just mandates that the type of `sizeof(expr)` is the same type as `std::size_t`. There is no mandate that using `sizeof(expr)` makes the name `std::size_t` available and since `std::size_t` just names one of the the built-in integral types there isn't really a problem.

Comment: It says that the type of `sizeof(expr)` _is_ `std::size_t`, which is where I have a problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There's a difference between *types* and *type names*. The type is always there, but the *name* isn't.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That sounds promising. Can you back it up with standard wording? I suppose it comes from the fact that numeric types cannot be magically created by a program, but it's all very indirect, isn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it is a bit like the symbol `1`: until you know how to write it, you can't spell it directly. Just because you don't know how to spell it it doesn't mean the concept isn't there.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I just find it hard to accept that `sizeof` be guaranteed to yield a `std::size_t` when that type name is not visible to the program. Or, at least, I wish the standard were clearer about this. I think the answer I'm looking for touches on `auto` with private types, and the `nullptr` debacle from http://stackoverflow.com/q/17069315/560648.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Also, I wish that an operator, which is part of the *core language,* weren't tied to a type available in the *library.* That's just conceptually wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it's quite straight-forward, isn't it? You can declare *names*, and you can define *types*. A type can have many names, declared with `typedef` or `using`, or as a template parameter, but only one definition - it's either built-in or user-defined. And traits only work on types, not names, so there's no trait to tell you whether something is a typedef or a primary name.

Comment: @H2CO3: The same observation, from the Lounge, spawned this question. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ugh... So it doesn't only twist my mind :P

Comment: @H2CO3: note that there is, conceptually, not separation between the language and the library! It is one thing and language features may be implemented in terms of what we might consider a library or library features could be implemented by the language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think the beginning of Clause 3 (Basic Concepts) contains useful pointers...

Comment: @H2CO3: Not necessarily. There are traits in the standard library that cannot be implemented without compiler support (`is_class` is one I think, plus all the traits like `is_nothrow_***_constructible`), yet they are exposed as class templates

Comment: @AndyProwl I beg to differ. "There are traits in the standard library that cannot be implemented without compiler support" - and who said that *this* was a good idea? The library and the core language should be entirely decoupled.

Comment: @H2CO3: There is probably not much point in re-designing the standard library such that it can function without the existence of the core language...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's not what I'm saying.

Comment: @H2CO3: Messin' with ya ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah OK :) Admittedly my phrasing wasn't perfect... but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: Anyway I believe the issue here lies in the distinction between types and their names. A type may exist and classify an expression even if it is unutterable (see lambdas). The fact that `sizeof(T)` yields the same type as `std::size_t` does not conflict with the fact that `std::size_t` may be unutterable (if `<cstddef>` was not included). Spelling out `sizeof(T)` does not assume you can "say" `std::size_t`.

Comment: @H2CO3: And don't forget the `std::typeinfo` situation. And the `std::initializer_list`...

Comment: @rodrigo I always tell people that there are a couple of very good reasons I don't like C++...

Comment: @H2CO3: I see what you mean, but then `std::is_class` should become an operator (e.g. `is_class()`). Not sure if I would like that. It would also mean I can't treat `is_class` as a class template if I need it (e.g. in generic code) - not saying it necessarily makes sense, might be a bad example.

Comment: @H2CO3: Separating the language core from the library is a pointless and arbitrary goal. What do you gain? C++ is a language comprised of syntax, semantics, and libraries, just like any other language.

Comment: @GManNickG I am not willing to argue about this further. "What do you gain" -- for example, interchangeability between compilers and libraries. (You seem to be an experienced C++ programmer. I am surprised and sad that you find this "arbitrary" and "pointless"...)

Comment: @H2CO3: That idea went down with varargs in C, about 3 decades ago. WG21 never assumed the two could be entirely separate.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, varargs in C are also guilty of blurring the borders. Horrible. One of the worst parts of C.

Comment: @H2CO3 A problem with operators like `is_class` is that functions called `is_class` now fail to compile.  If the only supported way to access it is via an include followed by using it, you get a pretty name *and* it doesn't break existing code (outside of extreme cases).  You could go with a `__is_class` operator (ie, use reserved tokens), but those look ugly.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `std::size_t` just names one of the the built-in integral types?   Who says a compiler implementer has to be sensible?

Comment: @Spencer: if the type of a `sizeof` expression isn’t `std::size_t` or this type doesn’t name one of the built-in integral types, the implementation doesn’t implement the C++ standard.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I was looking at the definition of `size_t` in the Standard and it seemed there was a loophole - it doesn't say it has to correspond to a _builtin_ integer type.

Comment: @Spencer: according to [support.types] `size_t` is an implementatio-defined integer type. OK, I see what you are saying: [basic.types] p11 defines the integer/integral types which include the unsigned integer types. … and the latter do include, according to [basic.types] p2, extended integer types. So the obious choice for a DS9k would be an extended unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, this standard passage requires the following expression:

```
typeid(sizeof(0)) == typeid(std::size_t)
```

will always yield `true`. If you use the actual identifier `std::size_t`, `::size_t` or any other alias/typedef will be irrelevant as long as the identity of the type, as per `std::typeinfo::operator==()`, is preserved.

The same *type identity* issue appears in other places of the language. For example, in my 64-bit machine the following code fails to compile because of function redefinition:

```
#include <cstddef>
void foo(std::size_t x)
{}

void foo(unsigned long x)
{}
```

Comment: So it should say "is a constant of type `std::size_t` (or the same type given by one of its other names, if that name is not visible to the program, just saying)"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But all this wording is unnecesary. If I write `typedef int number; number x;`, then `x` _is_ of type `int`, and it _is_ of type `number`, as they are the very same. Two names, one type.

Comment: It just unnerves me that this is left to the imagination.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But then, you'd have to do the same everywhere a specific type is required. Am I allowed to write `typedef int number; number main() {}`? If so, should the 3.6.1 say "It [main] shall have a return type of type int (or the same type given by one of its other names"?

Comment: That is a very good point. So the answer then is "live with it — it would be boring as heck if the standard didn't take these lexical 'shortcuts'!"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, I don't think you'll get enough momentum to convince the commitee to change this, But for you ease of mind, read 5.7.6: _"The type of the result [pointer substraction] is an implementation-defined signed integral
type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the <cstddef> header"_. And later, when pointers to the same object are substracted _"the result compares equal to the value 0 converted to the type
std::ptrdiff_t"_.

Comment: So there's a precedent! Now I'm even more keen for a canonical answer on this :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, `std::ptrdiff_t` is only named in 5.7.6/7, but `std::size_t` is all over the document. Particularly interesting is a note in 3.7.4: _"a new-expression, delete-expression or function call that refers to one of these functions [operator new/delete] without including the header <new> is well-formed. However, referring to std or std::size_t is ill-formed unless the name has been declared by including the appropriate header"_.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The type yielded by `sizeof` is some unsigned integer type; the implementation defines which one it is.

For example, on some particular implementation, the type of a `sizeof` expression might be `unsigned long`.

`std::size_t`, if it's a `typedef`, is nothing more than an alternative name for `unsigned long`. So these two statements:

> The type of `sizeof ...` is a constant of type `unsigned long`

and

> The type of `sizeof ...` is a constant of type `std::size_t`

are saying exactly the same thing *for that implementation*. The type `unsigned long` and the type `std::size_t` are the same type. The difference is that the latter is accurate for all (conforming) implementations, where `std::size_t` might be an alias for, say, `unsigned int` or some other unsigned type.

As far as the compiler is concerned, `sizeof` yields a result of type `unsigned long`; the compiler (as opposed to the runtime library) needn't have any knowledge of the name `size_t`.

This all assumes that `std::size_t` (or just `size_t` if you're talking about C) is a typedef. That's not spelled out in either the C or the C++ standard. Nevertheless, an implementation can straightforwardly conform to the requirements of the standard by making `size_t` a typedef. I don't believe there's any other *portable* way to satisfy those requirements. (It can't be a macro or an implementation-defined keyword because that would infringe on the user's name space, and a macro wouldn't be scoped within the `std` namespace.) A compiler *could* make `size_t` some implementation-specific construct other than a typedef, but since a typedef works perfectly well, there's no point in doing so. It would be nice, IMHO, if the standard stated that `size_t` is a typedef.

(An irrelevant aside: The real problem is that the standard refers to the result as a "constant". In ISO C, a "constant" is a token, such as an integer literal. C++, as far as I know, doesn't define the noun "constant", but it does refer to the ISO C definition of the term. `sizeof ...` is a constant *expression*; it's not a *constant*. Calling the result a "constant value" would have been reasonable.)

Comment: This all seems to rely on `std::size_t` being a typedef.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What else could it be?

Comment: Nothing I suppose. Would still prefer it spelt out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same type but you have to include that header to use it.

Comment: I just used it in the variable `x`, without any trouble, without including the header.