# Is this valid C++ code? (Using local type outside scope of declaration)

Tags: c++

Is the following code valid according to (any) C++ ISO standards?

```
#include <functional>

auto a() {
    struct Foo {
    };
    return []() {return Foo{}; };
}

int main()
{
    auto l = a()();
    decltype(l) ll;
    //Foo f; //error: unknown type name 'Foo'
    return 0;
}
```

[The compilers](https://godbolt.org/g/HZYRDN) (Visual studio 2015, latest Clang and latest GCC) accept this but it seems weird that decltype should give me access to Foo.

Comment: Yes, since C++11.

Comment: Note that you don't need `<functional>` for lambdas. Though you do if you want to use `std::function`, which is a convenient type for storing a lambda.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Was a bit miffed that @BaummitAugen [correctly] found an [accurate] duplicate after I'd answered this question. Turns out I answered the duplicate too. Winning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was even the *only* dupe of this I found in the first couple of pages. Tbh, I had expected there to be a couple more, but then, google was not great in understanding my query.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Ironically, the only possible dupe I could think of, was a question that _I_ asked (see comments under my answer)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

It is actually the *name* of the type that is scoped, not the type itself.

You're not using its name, so everything is fine.

Comment: I once asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20808905/560648).

Comment: Thanks, see my follow up question.