# Why is nullptr_t not a keyword

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a declaration of `nullptr_t` in `<cstddef>` :

```
namespace std {
  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069315/what-is-the-type-of-nullptr), `std::nullptr_t` is an alias for some unspecified fundamental type of which `nullptr` is an instance. So the actual type of `nullptr` doesn't have a name (well, the language does not give it a name, the name was given by standard library).

`nullptr` itself is a keyword. But standard did not introduce a keyword for type of `nullptr`. Instead using `decltype(nullptr)` is offered.

What are reasons for doing this? I found it much confusing. You need to include header and specify `std::` for just using a language built-in feature.

Is this to keep the set of C++ keywords as small as possible? Is this specifically for `nullptr` or committee is going to declare all new types like this, so we would have `namespace std { typedef decltype(false) bool; }` if such decision was made earlier?

Comment: Yes, nothing breaks existing code worse than adding new keywords to a language.  Contextual keywords like `enum class`, `final`, `override` are a decent alternative btw.

Comment: But it's also the easiest thing to detect and fix (of course there are always pathological cases, e.g. code generation). Cosidering this, there are probably a myriad worse ways to break existing code.

Comment: Adding new keywords introduces potential breaks for existing code which the committee tries to avoid if possible. See [Why are override and final identifiers with special meaning instead of reserved keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30404388/1708801) for the rationale for not making override and final reserved words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the initial proposal of `nullptr`, [N2431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf) (**Emphasis Mine**):

> We propose a new standard reserved word `nullptr`. The `nullptr` keyword
>   designates a constant rvalue of type `decltype(nullptr)`. We also
>   provide the `typedef`: `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;` **`nullptr_t` is
>   not a reserved word.** It is a `typedef` (as its `_t` `typedef` indicates) for
>   `decltype(nullptr)` defined in `<cstddef>`. **We do not expect to see much
>   direct use of nullptr_t in real programs.**

Generally, the committee is reluctant in the addition of new keywords in the language. In my humble opinion this is for a good reason, named **backward compatibility.**

If you further read the proposal, you'd realize that the main concern is not breaking existing code.

Imagine the effect that would have if the committee now and then introduced a new keyword. All hell would break loose and C++ from a success story would have been a big joke.

Comment: However new keyword for `nullptr` was added. I'm sure it has higher chances that someone already used `nullptr` in their code than used `nullptr_t` because "We do not expect to see much direct use of nullptr_t in real programs."

Comment: so new types are expected to be added to `std` namespace?

Comment: @anton_rh They proposed `nullptr` to be a keyword. "We propose a new standard reserved word nullptr.". The name was chosen after an informal pole and google search.

Comment: @anton_rh Trust the committee they're wise. They have to consider things that we are not aware of and make the best compromise out of them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason is simple: the standardization committee wants to avoid as much as reasonably possible to introduce new keywords (because, given the billions lines of *existing* C++ code, it is likely to conflict with some code somewhere).

Since `std::nullptr_t`  is definable, it does not need to be a keyword.

And `bool`  is a keyword for historical reasons. It very probably has been introduced quite early...

C++ is mostly about legacy software, so human and social and economical considerations (and backward compatibility) matters a lot for the standardization committee (often more than technical reasons alone).

Comment: we can avoid using keywords at all. Just use `std::` for everything. `std::int int = 10, while = 0; std::while(int > while) ...`

Comment: But the C++ committee did not want that. FWIW PL/1 is a language without keywords, so `IF IF=THEN THEN ELSE=IF;` is valid in PL/1 but unreadable

Answer (score 3):

Adding new keywords are avoided when not necessary. Why add something to the language when it can just be added to the library.

You already have a similar thing with `sizeof(x)` which returns `std::size_t`, which you also have to include a header to get the typedef for.

Comment: I thought that `size_t` is just a typedef to `unsigned int` or something else that is correct for the platform running code. No built-in features here.

Comment: @anton - Yes, `std::size_t` is a typedef, just like `std::nullptr_t`.  :-)  And the compiler can return a value of that type for `sizeof`, just like it can return a value for `nullptr`, even if none of the typedefs are visible. No difference!

Comment: I was sure that *size_t* is mapped to existing *named* type (like _unsigned int_). That is difference. Though can't find it in `stddef.h` and become thinking it's magic too... O_o

Comment: Found a good thread that exposes analogy between std::nullptr_t and std::size_t: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20809166/5447906