# If nullptr_t isn't a keyword, why are char16_t and char32_t?

Tags: c++, c++11

As discussed at [Why is nullptr_t not a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107491/why-is-nullptr-t-not-a-keyword), it is better to avoid introducing new keywords because they can break backward compatibility.

Why then are `char16_t` and `char32_t` keywords, when they could just as well have been defined like so?

```
namespace std {
    typedef decltype(u'q') char16_t;
    typedef decltype(U'q') char32_t;
}
```

Comment: It's new to me these aren't typedefs anymore. Where did you get that claim from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ They are listed as keywords in the standard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: C++11 says they're keywords. (§2.12)

Comment: `char16_t` and `char32_t` are fundamental types, they aren't declared in `std`, I suppose you could argue that they could have been but presumably the working group wanted them as part of the C++ core.

Comment: @user657267 The discrepancy between those types and `nullptr_t` is what puzzles me. This could've been a mere oversight, but I find it unlikely that nobody on the committee proposed making `char16_t` and `char32_t` *not* keywords.

Comment: +1 but actually it would have been quite disturbing using `std::char32_t` all around instead of `char32_t`. That said, good question.

Comment: I *think* this has to do with C compatibility, which defines the same two types.

Comment: @user657267 That seems like a possible rationale, although not a compelling one since it does not seem that C++ was designed to be compatible with features added to C after C++98. For example, there is no `_Complex` in C++.

Comment: I guess they want legal C codes that uses `typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;` to fail loudly.

Comment: The wchar_t debacle ought to be inspirational.  If it would be a typedef then somebody can #include a .h file that makes it something else and you're back to having no use for it.

Comment: @Brian The fact that there's no `_Complex` in C++ means it _is_ compatible. The name in C doesn't conflict with the name of something different in C++.

Comment: Isn't the answer to this question inherently based on the opinions of people we may not have access to? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The proposal itself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2249.html) explains why: to allow overloading with the underlying types of `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`. If they were `typedef`ed this wouldn't be possible.

> Define `char16_t` to be a distinct new type, that has the same size and representation as `uint_least16_t`. Likewise, define `char32_t` to be a distinct new type, that has the same size and representation as `uint_least32_t`.
>
> [N1040 defined `char16_t` and `char32_t` as typedefs to `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, which make overloading on these characters impossible.]

As for why they aren't in the `std` namespace, this is for compatibility with the original C proposal. C++ prohibits the C definitions from appearing in its own version of `<cuchar>`

[c.strings] / 3

> The headers shall not define the types `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` (2.11).

The types then would need to be global typedefs, which carries its own set of issues such as

```
typedef decltype(u'q') char16_t;

namespace foo {
  typedef int char16_t;
}
```

The reason for `std::nullptr_t` not being a keyword can be found in the question you linked

> We do not expect to see much direct use of `nullptr_t` in real programs.

making `nullptr_t` the real exception here.

Comment: The typedef approach I suggested in the question avoids this pitfall: they can be distinct types and yet still be typedefs, the same way as `decltype(nullptr)`.

Comment: @Brian I've added some more thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Because of naughty code like this:

```
typedef uint16_t char16_t;

extern char * strndup16to8 (const char16_t* s, size_t n);
extern size_t strnlen16to8 (const char16_t* s, size_t n);
```

Sure, the *existence* of C++11 aware compilers doesn't preclude the existence of C++03 libraries or the plethora of systems or users that use C++03 compilers/libraries.

If you're lucky, they'll do this:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 201112L && __cplusplus < 201103L
   typedef uint16_t char16_t;
#endif
```

Comment: How does changing them from typedefs solve that behavior?